# Перемещение окон в MacOS

Tags: macos

После 7-ми лет использования linux mint на cinnamon, пересел на macOS.
В cinnamon есть шикарная возможность, при зажатом alt можно тащить окна за любую область.
Кто-нибудь в курсе, можно ли что-то подобное сделать в macOS, чтобы при зажатии нужной клавиши, можно было перетаскивать окна **не** только за заголовок?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/53051/altclick-drag-window-resizing-on-a-mac-similar-to-x-windows

Comment: Большое спасибо! https://github.com/dmarcotte/easy-move-resize
работает отлично.